# ProxyPass tags meaning

Tags: apache-1.3

```
    <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:444>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
<Directory /home/test/public_beta>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
DocumentRoot /home/test/public_beta
ServerName me.dev

ProxyPass / http://me.dev:8044
ProxyPassReverse / http://me.dev:8044
```

What does above mean?  Will it redirect request to port 8044 to / or /var/www/html ?
whats does Directory and DocumentRoot mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<Directory>` directive is used to assign special commands just for that hard-drive location, in this case, it tells apache what to do when it encounters an `.htaccess` file in that directory.
The `DocumentRoot` tells apache where the 'home page' web files would be, if it weren't for the `ProxyPass` directive, which tells apache to redirect EVERYTHING to me.dev on port 8044.

I bet if you commented them out it would work exactly the same.

There is a complete guide to all the directives online: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/

Basically, every request (including redirects) will be proxied to `http://me.dev:8044`

For instance, `https://localhost:444/something/page.html` should respond from `http://me.dev:8044/something/page.html`

Comment: thanks Grizly,for detailed explanation. I have issue,localhost:444/something works when i tried it from localmachine. But when I try  this from different machine (say from virtual machine) i did something like ipaddress:444/something  -- its not working. Will it work?

Comment: No, your `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:444>` explicitly only refers to the localhost. You should change that to your actual IP address for remote machines to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

this will redirect Request to http://127.0.0.1:444/ to http://me.dev:8044/. This snippets doesn't tell whether the directory behind http://me.dev:8044/ is / or /var/www/html. The DocumentRoot and Directory Settings is not really necessary because of the ProxyPass directive.

you can find even more details in the documentation:
[ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_proxy.html)
[DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html)

Comment: thanks.How to find "This snippets doesn't tell whether the directory behind http://me.dev:8044/ is / or /var/www/html. " ? should i look into /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file?

Comment: It might be this file. You have to search for the configuration of the virtual host me.dev with Port 8044.

Comment: thanks Christian,both you answered my questions.thanks a lot.